# Writing from console to text file, file data not saved

Tags: java, file, fwrite

I am trying to save  the content of the java console into a text file but each time I close the program the text file goes blank and rewrites to it.  i.e. if I write to a file today, close the program and come back and run it again tomorrow, it has remembered the information written to it.

Comment: can you paste a small example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Check out [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/).

Comment: yes, I am using Scanner class to read the user inputs and using PrintWriter to write them into a file, i am trying to write the data so it remains within the text file and not wiped after each time i close the program.

Comment: No no - paste your code into the question.  A description of the code is not going to help us root cause.

Comment: @jahroy Using Log4J is pretty much overkill if you aren't doing anything (similar to) logging. Writing simply to a textfile is no excuse, IMHO, to "just use Log4j because it knows how to append". Native streams support appending just as well.

Comment: @RobIII - That's true...  But it does sound like the OP is after functionality similar to logging: He wants his program to continually append to the same file each time it runs.

Comment: @jahroy So you're saying "*continually appending to the same file*" == logging?!? Logging usually implies some sort of format like `<datetime> <type> <event>` (e.g. `2013-03-18T06:46:21 WARNING Foo bar baz`). What if he wants to append customers to a file? What if the application "continually" adds customers to a file because it is 'converting' format A to B and that's all the application does? I think it's not safe to assume that 'continually appending to a file' automatically equals 'logging'; not even by a long shot.

Comment: @RobIII - Um... sorry.  Nevermind.  I made a simple statement saying it was _similar_.  Didn't mean to incite a debate (yikes).  You are right and my original suggestion was misguided (although all I did was say "_check it out_").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to open the `OutputStream` in [*append mode*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29). Demo code:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                     new FileOutputStream(new File(filename), true));
```

What you experience is the normal behavior when you write a stream to a file, and this is not specific to the Java API.

Comment: +1; I would have added a [reference to the documentation](<http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String, boolean)>) pointing out the second constructor having a second boolean argument named "append" though for completeness.

Comment: Thanks :) Already did that, but hey! cache invalidation on the SO's servers is one of the two hardest things in CS :P

Comment: LOL @ cache invalidation! :D